# Use checkbox to enable fields

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access database with several fields that are check boxes that correspond to other fields such as an ID# and date. I want these fields to be grayed out when the corresponding check box is not selected and to open up when selected.

`Check box: Study`

`Field 1: StudyID`

`Fields 2: StudyDate`

The 2 fields have been disabled for default. I am using the following code for `AfterUpdate` on the checkbox:

```
If Me.Study Then
    StudyID.Enabled = True
    StudyDate.Enabled = True
Else
    StudyID.Enabled = False
    StudyDate.Enabled = False
End If
```

This makes it sort of work. It works on action when you click but it doesn't save the change when you switch records or close/reopen the form. Is this the right code, or is there something better, or does each record need to be individually linked?

Comment: Please specify exactly what behaviour you want to see when you move to another record, and then move back to _this_ record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that the code needs to run again "On Current".  That way every time you change back to the form, it will look to see if the checkbox is checked, and enable/disable the fields correctly.

Select the form (click the little square at top left where the rulers intersect), then on the Event properties tab click "On Current".  Load this code:

```
If Me.Study = -1 Then
    StudyID.Enabled = True
    studydate.Enabled = True
Else
    StudyID.Enabled = False
    studydate.Enabled = False
End If
```